# Clock running fast after OS X Mavericks install

Tags: osx-mavericks, date-time, clock

I've noticed my OS X system time on my iMac is running faster after I updated to Mavericks, after about a week it is a good 4 or 5 minutes too fast.

In my Date & Time preferences everything is set to automatic, time is set to update using `Apple Europe (time.euro.apple.com.)` and the time zone is set to automatic too.

Any idea why this could be happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: It could just be that the internal clock battery is dying. Automatic time sync doesn't happen continuously. How old is your iMac?

Comment: I bought it around March 2010. Never had this issue before with older macs though :-/

Comment: It'll definitely happen _eventually_, but yeah, 3.5 years is way too short. Curious.

Comment: This has been bugging me for the last few weeks as well.  Over the long holiday weekend my system was off by 5 1/2 minutes.  Opening the date/time preferences pane causes it to sync immediately.  I called apple support regarding this a bit ago; they had me reset the BMC and PRAM.  I'm running a script every 5 minutes to track the differences between my system clock and their time server.  After 5 minutes it's clear it's running too fast and not syncing up to ntp as it should.  This is a Late 2012 iMac I've had for only 3 months (as a replacement for another iMac apple couldn't fix).

Comment: @yoonix Shame that resetting the BMC and PRAM didn't work as I hadn't tried that yet. Tempted to set a script to run `ntpdate` every few hours but I'd rather find out what the problem is!

Comment: Yesterday my case was 'escalated to engineering'.  I've seen others claim success by rebooting into safe mode then rebooting back into normal.  Didn't work for me though.

Comment: FWIW, I did a full clean installation of Mavericks on an external USB HDD (since that's what the last two reps I spoke with were suggesting I do).  My time drift is nowhere as bad as it was before, but it's still there.  I was losing .2 seconds/5 min before, losing ~.015/5min on the new installation.

Comment: Still no long term fix, but I compiled my own ntpd from NTP.org and that works fine (using the same config files from the broken one).  The support guy I've got sounds like he's planning on following this through until resolution.  No idea when that might be though.  So far he's returned every call and email I've sent.  Quite surprised by the follow through.  While I have access to corporate support, I just called in using the 90 day installation and setup support.

Comment: I haven't heard back with any resolution yet, but I installed 10.9.1 earlier today and it appears my problem has gone away.  I've been running for ~3 hours and my time is off 0.015224 sec and slowly decreasing on the first system I updated.

Comment: I've updated to 10.9.1 too and I'm seeing that is seems to be fixed as well. Great news! I'll check back in a few days.

Comment: Well, it's been just over 10 days since upgrading to 10.9.1 and my clock is about 10 minutes fast :-S

Comment: Yeah, happened to me as well.  Not as bad as before, but I'm 34 seconds behind after a week or so.

Comment: They made the clock run faster... now only if they could apply that to the computer itself...

Comment: All of the answers regarding a fix that just gets the NTPD working are so frustrating to me. That is a bandaid. A modern clock going 5 minutes fast over the course of a *week* is simply unacceptable. What is the real fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

My iMac suffered from the same inaccurate clock syndrome.  However my MacBook Pro set up exactly the same with Mavericks and on the same network keeps time very well.

The problematic iMac was reporting an inability to "create socket" in the system.log.  It looks like it was trying to set the time every 5 minutes when I looked in the system.log

```
$ grep ntpd /var/log/system.log    returned many of these, each about 5 minutes apart:

Dec 19 15:32:46 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[8887]: unable to create socket on en1 (53) for 2002:43ba:cb7b::a82a:82b9:92d0:134#123  
Dec 19 15:37:47 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[8887]: unable to create socket on en0 (54) for 2002:43ba:cb7b::701a:38b1:c1e9:db4d#123
```

As a shot in the dark I changed the time server in the Date & Time prefs by pasting a server from a near-by city over the Apple (time.apple.com) entry.  I used `ntp-nist.ldsbc.edu`.

Now the time is updating periodically and seems to be accurate.

`$ grep ntpd /var/log/system.log`     now returns entries like these and looks like it is updating the time appropriately:

```
Dec 19 15:53:15 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[124]: proto: precision = 1.000 usec  
Dec 19 15:57:43 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[124]: SYNC state ignoring -0.128408 s  
Dec 19 15:58:49 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[124]: SPIK state ignoring -0.159852 s  
Dec 19 16:19:45 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[124]: ntpd: time set -0.224141 s  
Dec 19 16:55:43 Macintosh-0023dffe31b2.local ntpd[124]: ntpd: time set -1.573103 s
```

I hope this continues to solve my problem.

Comment: Well, it didn't stick. My clock drift is back and the system log shows that the computer is again "unable to create socket"  So just changing the time server fixed the problem for about a day but is not a permanent solution. The computer is running 10.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding the following line to /etc/ntp.conf

```
interface ignore ipv6
```

and then restarting ntpd.

It appears to work just fine using ivp4 instead of ipv6

Comment: Sounds like a bug...

Comment: After upgrading to 10.9.2 this no longer seems necessary. I'm not getting any more "unable to create socket" errors in my logs. I guess Apple fixed this in one of their updates.

Comment: Hehe! Called it!